# wordpress site not starting

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have moved wordpress site to production server from test server. I have done database, code configuration changes. The strange problem i am facing is if i call my website adding index.php then only it shows the site.

http://www.suziesellsaz.com/index.php

If i directly call using domain name it is not working

http://www.suziesellsaz.com

I have thought problem may be because of .htaccess so i have deleted .htacess and saved permalink and it creates following .htaccess but still no luck.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can some one help me solving the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you for your valuable help and inputs. I struggled a lot on this issue and able to find the solution following these steps. Hope it will help some like me.

@ Always use domain name in lower case.

- In my case client domain is "SuzieSellsAZ.com" treat it as "suziesellsaz.com" all lower case.
- Use Database Search and Replace Script in PHP to replace all occurence of previous domain.

ref:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 1):

Please check if under **Settings > General settings**

Both the urls i.e **Wordpress Address** and **Site Address** are same.

Last time I had this issue when they were different. Changing them and reseting permalink fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Thanks..Both are same currently.. point to "http://www.SuzieSellsAZ.com"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but, Put your htaccess file back and

```
RewriteBase /
```

replace with this

```
RewriteBase /public_html/
```

and

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

replace with this

```
RewriteRule . /public_html/index.php [L]
```

May be it's the problem of URL rewriting.

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: I update the answer and try with that. Put the folder name that you created as per your directory listing.

Comment: Thanks..Tried this as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in **.htaccess** file -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Once done then please make sure that the site URL and home URL for your site are set correctly. You can update the **site URL and home URL** from **wp_options** table, **WordPress configuration file** or from the **WordPress administration panel**.

Once done then please clear the cache of your system and try to access the website.

Let us know how you go.

Comment: If i add above content to .htaccess it started giving "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request." and nothing working admin panel nor site

Answer (score 0):

Update the siteurl and home URL in database options table and all other occurrence in the database.

Once it done or database update then you should import to any server and it will works fine.

Sometime site post or page URL does not work then go to **setting > permalinks** and save it. Site post and page URL will work fine.